# How do I list all the files in a subversion repository, offline?

Tags: svn

Normally, I would use `svn list -R .` to find out all the files in a subversion repository that I've checked out.

However, for large repos, like LLVM, it's simply too slow.

```
$ svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
... lots of files
 U   llvm
Checked out revision 262801.
$ cd llvm
$ time svn list -R . > files.txt
svn list -R . > files.txt  0.79s user 0.13s system 0% cpu 1:50.73 total
```

Almost two minutes! I can do better with `find` (though I will need to filter out `.svn` afterwards):

```
$ time find . -type f > find_files.txt 
find . -type f > find_files.txt  0.02s user 0.02s system 98% cpu 0.040 total
```

It seems that subversion is making a network request for all 20,000 files in the repo! If I remove my network connection:

```
$ time svn list -R . > files_offline.txt
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk'
svn: E670002: Name or service not known
svn list -R . > files_offline.txt  0.02s user 0.01s system 41% cpu 0.056 total
```

Can I list all the files in my local subversion checkout without using the network?

Answer (score 3):

**UPD**: If you are a windows user you can download the `svncmd` tools from here:
https://github.com/andry81/svncmd
See the `svn_list.bat` script here:
https://github.com/andry81/svncmd/tree/HEAD/Scripts/svn_list.bat

**Usage examples**:

1. `call svn_list.bat -offline branch/current > files.lst`
2. `call svn_list.bat -offline -wcroot branch/current branch/current/myproject > files.lst`

---

SVN wc.db is the sqlite database. You can use the "Command Line Shell For SQLite" to access the SVN database file directly: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

For example, 1.9.4 database implementation contains these tables:

- NODES
- NODES_CURRENT
- NODES_BASE

Differences between tables are in what has been changed from the last commit over the repository:

- The NODES_BASE table stores the base state of local files and folders associated with particular revision each. For example, that state is what you get when update the Working Copy to the particular revision but before the local changes has take a place.
- The NODES_CURRENT table stores the same entries as the NODES_BASE stores minus entries with files/folder which will be removed from the NODES_BASE after commit and plus entries with files/folders requested for add/remove to the NODES_BASE before commit. This means that the files/folders entries requested for remove will be shown in the table only once (no entry duplication).
- The NODES table stores the same entries as the NODES_BASE stores plus entries with files/folders requested for add/remove to the NODES_BASE. This means that the files/folders entries requested for remove will be shown in the table twice because entries requested for remove already has been existed in the NODES_BASE table.

So, if you want the base file list with local change entries, then you have to use the NODES_CURRENT table. If you want the base file list without local change entries, then you have to use the NODES_BASE table.

Here is the usage examples for the Windows batch shell:

- Base state without any local changes:
- sqlite3.exe -batch wc.db ".headers off" "select local_relpath from nodes_base where local_relpath != ''"
- Changed state with entries of removed files and folders:
- sqlite3.exe -batch wc.db ".headers off" "select local_relpath from nodes_current where local_relpath != ''"
- Changed state without entries of removed files and folders
- sqlite3.exe -batch wc.db ".headers off" "select local_relpath from nodes_current where local_relpath != '' and presence = 'normal'"

**TIP:**
To lookup the wc.db file, for example, directly from the Total Commander by the F3 key, you can install sqliteviewer plugin.

**TIP2:**
You have to dump every ".svn/wc.db" file on the way down the Working Copy directory tree (recursively) to get all files list as the "svn list -R ." does.

**TIP3:**
The "svn list" dumps the NODES_BASE entries (first example).

**TIP4:**
Output from the "svn list" will slightly differ than from the local_relpath field because:

- Directories has stored without trailing slash.
- In Windows Console utf-8 is not default code page and sqlite executable will use current console code page to translate the output.
- The "svn list" does use current locale output and slightly different string ascending sort.
- 

If you want to correct at least utf-8 output and trailing slash, for example, in Windows Console you have to write set of commands and complicate the SQL request:

```
chcp 65001
sqlite3.exe -batch wc.db ".headers off" "with new_nodes as ( select case when kind != 'dir' then local_relpath else local_relpath || '/' end as new_paths from nodes_base where local_relpath != '') select * from new_nodes order by new_paths asc"
```

The output will be almost close sorted to the "svn list" output except wrong order between lines with '/', '.' and ' ' characters in the same position.

Answer (score 2):

```
svn status -v
```

Can give you desired info, however - it requires some pre-processing given output. Here is some code snippet with C#:

```
/// <summary>
/// Lists all files being under svn version control, recursively. Does not include directories.
/// 
/// Does not list newly added files (Which are not yet committed)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path">Path where to take files</param>
/// <returns>List of files</returns>
static public List<String> svnGetFileList( String path, bool bRecursive = true)
{
    // If you're online - this kind of line can be used.
    //List<String> l = ExecCmd("svn ls \"" + path + "\" " + ((bRecursive) ? "--recursive" : "")).Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    String svnStatusText = ExecCmd("svn status -v \"" + path + "\" ");

    List<String> l = Regex.Matches(svnStatusText, "^[^?].{6} +[0-9]+ +[0-9]+ +(.*?) +([^\r\n]+)", RegexOptions.Multiline).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[2].Value).ToList();
    // [^?] - all versioned files only - status must not contain '?' - unversioned.
    // skip 6 character columns (one character wide).
    // skip 2 svn revisions
    // skip svn login (.*) - non greedy match.

    for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
    {
        if (l[i].Length <= path.Length)             // Only for first entry (directory name)
        {
            l.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
            continue;
        }

        if (Directory.Exists(l[i]))
        {
            l.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
            continue;
        }

        l[i] = l[i].Substring(path.Length + 1);     // Cut off main path.

        if (!bRecursive && l[i].Contains("\\"))     // Don't list sub-folders
        {
            l.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return l;
}



/// <summary>
/// Executes command and throw exception if something unexpected happened.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cmd">command to execute</param>
/// <returns>String logged from standard output and standard error</returns>
public static String ExecCmd(String cmd)
{
    String error = "";
    if (!ExecCmd(cmd, ref error))
    {
        throw new Exception(error);
    }

    return error;
} //ExecCmd


/// <summary>
/// Executes command and returns standard output & standard error to error string.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>true if error code was 0, false if something else</returns>
public static bool ExecCmd(String cmd, ref String error)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    // Whole command should be quoted.
    // cmd.exe /C ""mytool.exe" "c:\mypath\myfile.txt""
    //            ^                                   ^                                   ^
    // https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/03ea84cf-19a6-450d-a3d6-8a139857e0cd/help-with-paths-containing-spaces
    //
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C \"" + cmd + "\" 2>&1";
    // Console.WriteLine("Executing 'cmd.exe " + p.StartInfo.Arguments + "'");
    p.Start();
    error = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();

    if (p.ExitCode != 0)
    {
        error += "\r\n  (Executed command was: " + cmd + ")";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
} //ExecCmd
```